# How to pass json data to ejs frontend

Tags: reactjs, ejs

I am trying to pass json data from backend to ejs frontend, here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Advanced React Application Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.initialData = <%- JSON.stringify(initialData) -%>
</script>
</head>


<body>
<div id="root">
    <%- initialMarkup -%>
        <%- JSON.stringify(initialData) -%>
</div>
</body>
<!-- place the bundle file in th public dir -->
<script src="/bundle.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>

</html>
```

I got the syntax error in this, it said it couldn't find the initialData, but in the body part the data render without any problem. Could anyone know what is the error here?

```
   window.initialData = <% - JSON.stringify(initialData) %>
```

Below is my data from server side code:

```
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
   const initialContent = await serverRender();
   res.render("index", {
      initialData: initialContent.initialData,
      initialMarkup: initialContent.initialMarkup,

  });
 });
```

The initialData is json format. Below is the sample data:

```
 {articles: [
  {
    id: "95c12a8f6c88953ca8f8a39da25546e6",
    title: "Introducing React's Error Code System",
    date: "Mon Jul 11 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
    authorId: "2c6aa2cfe3449467d329fa17d6ea230f",
    body:
      "Building"
    }],
    authors: [
        {
          id: "d85577ea34ae50f2dac5347b5219aa23",
          firstName: "Andrew",
          lastName: "Clark",
          website: "https://twitter.com/acdlite"
         }]
     }
```

Comment: Could you provide us with the output HTML please? And eventually what `initialData` look like?

Comment: I add some details. Thanks

Comment: You are using `<%-` EJS tags, in both places, for unescaped strings. I think this should work in the HTML `<body>` section of your `index.ejs` file, but maybe not within the `<script>` section (where unescaped quotation marks seem likely to give you problems). What if you used an escaped HTML tag (`<%=`) instead?